# Cannot resolve method 'getWindow()'

Tags: android

The `getWindow()` method in the following line of code

> this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

results in the following error

> Cannot resolve method 'getWindow()'

The faulty line of code is at the bottom of this method

```
private void setButtonListener(Button button){
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String textString = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(textString);
            editText.getText().clear();


            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(), 0);

            this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
}
```

I want my `editText` to lose focus when the keyboard is closed.

I'm in an activity class so I'm not sure what the problem is. Does `this` have a `getWindow()` method?

Comment: Inside onClick, this refers to the OnClickListener.  You need to use MyTopLevelClassName.this instead.

Answer (score 3):

Find the solution

In Activity :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

In Fragment :

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnFocusChangeListener to hidden soft keyboard and lose focus

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
OnFocusChangeListener ofcListener = new MyFocusChangeListener();
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);


private class MyFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.textbox && !hasFocus) {

            InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can close soft keyboard like this

```
private void setButtonListener(Button button){
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String textString = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(textString);
            editText.getText().clear();


            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);

        }
    });
}
```

If you want to toggle

```
InputMethodManager im =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution-> just **add class** name ahead of **this**.

```
MainActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.getWindow()` use  `YourActivity.this.getWindow()`

**Try this:**

```
YourActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```